# Cast from base class to a specific derived class when using a vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++, g++

As a way to learn C++, I've been trying to create a program for the past few days that stores information for different types of media that I plan to watch, am currently watching, and have already watched.

I have this code so far:

```cpp
class Media {
public:
    virtual ~Media() = default;
    virtual void DisplayInfo() { //display title }
    std::string title;
}

class Book : public Media {
public:
    void DisplayInfo() { //call function from base, then display volume }
    int volume;
}

class Series : public Media {
public:
    void DisplayInfo() { //call function from base, then display episode}
    int episode;
}

// Assume I have constructors for each class
```

Then, I want to be able to add to each list, display an element's information, delete an element, etc., each of which I can figure out how to do if I do this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Media>> books;
books.push_back(make_shared<Book>("Test", 1));
```

And then just do `books[i]->DisplayInfo()` which will still call `Book::DisplayInfo()`.

However, I also want to be able to edit (and save to a file) member values of each derived class, like `books[i]->volume = 2`, but I have no idea how to make this work.

I have books, series, and movies, and I have a planned, current, and completed version of each, so I want to avoid having to hard-code which list to use based on the user's input, because I would essentially have 9 `if` statements that each have a `switch` statement with 4 cases for each list operation (show, add, edit, delete).

I also have different methods for each derived class, like `AddToCurrentBookList()`, `AddToPlannedBookList()`, etc, because they all have different members.

I need to be able to utilize the polymorphism from the base class, but then also cast to a specific derived class depending on what the user chooses. For example, if the user decides to work on their planned book list and they want to edit some values for one of the entries, I need to be able to get that specific `PlannedBook` list, use the corresponding function for that type, and then edit that derived class's members, then go back and do the same for a different list.

Is there some way of having a function that returns the list I need as a `std::vector<std::shard_ptr<Media>>`, and then having some kind of a `Type` class that holds the type I want so that I can cast that list to that type at run time? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about exactly what you want. If you want to treat a vector of book objects as a vector of books then don't store them in a vector of Media, store them in a vector of books. If for some reason you need them to be Media -- if you  are leveraging polymorphism in some way -- then you need to explain why you need vectors of Media.

Comment: I didn't think of this until now but I may be able to use virtual functions in my classes for editing members, which would then still allow me to use vectors of media to pass around to each function, but then call media->Edit() to change the derived class's members. I can't try it out right now so this might not be viable

Comment: @jwezorek I need to be able to easily pass the chosen list around various functions, and then cast when I need to. For example if I have a DisplayAllInfo() function that takes in a vector of books and calls books[i]->DisplayInfo() for each entry, then I won't be able to use it for any other type of media, so I need it to be generic and take in a vector of media, which I can then downcast to the type I need at run time for other functions that need a specific derived type.

Comment: See my answer regarding casting shared_ptrs. You could also use vectors of books etc instead of of Media but then make functions like DisplayAllInfo() be function templates e.g. `template <typename T> DisplayAllInfo(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& media)`

Answer (score 3):

Well there is no way to cast a `vector<T>` to a `vector<U>`. You could copy it, casting item by item, of course.

So I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for but it occurs to me that you may not know about `std::static_pointer_cast`. It is the equivalent of `static_cast` but for shared pointers. It allows you to do things like the following

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Media>> books_as_media_ptrs;
books_as_media_ptrs.push_back(std::make_shared<Book>("Test", 1));

// make it a book again...
std::shared_ptr<Book> book_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<Book>(books_as_media_ptrs[0]);

book_ptr->setBookTitle("i'm a book!");
```

There is also a `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Comment: "*There is also a `dynamic_pointer_cast`*" - ie: `std::shared_ptr<Book> book_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Book>(books_as_media_ptrs[0]); if (book_ptr) { book_ptr->setBookTitle("i'm a book!"); } else { /* not a book, do something else */ }`